# AWS Python Lambda Unable to Import Module In zip File constructed on CodeBuild

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zip, aws-codebuild

I am trying to deploy a [python lambda function with a zip file archive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-package-with-dependency).

Using AWS CodeBuild I followed the instructions to setup a zip file with my [source code and dependencies at the top level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-package-with-dependency).

However, when I invoke my Lambda function an import error is reported:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'my_module': No module named 'cytoolz.itertoolz'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "<random uuid>",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

**Why is Lambda unable to find a dependency that exists within a zip file that is built using CodeBuild?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with python versions.  The [`Standard 6.0`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) CodeBuild environment has python `3.10` installed but the python runtime environment in Lambda only goes up to `3.9` (at the time of this answer).

Therefore, when installing the dependencies into the zip file

```
pip install --target ./package requests

cd package 
zip -r ../my-deployment-package.zip .
```

The version of pip is 3.10 and all of the dependencies that are installed and packaged in the zip file are the wrong python version.

In CodeBuild install a python & pip 3.9 to create the zip file.